# After performing a feature merge, are we supposed to delete the branch, or merge back later?

Tags: tfs, version-control, merge, branching-and-merging

Using TFS, but the question seems appropriate for any version control system.

In the following scenario I created a local folder named `dev\1\< project >` next to the `main` folder for feature 1 development as a branch off of the main.  I merged it back when feature 1 was completed.

When it comes time to work on feature 4, should I merge the main back to the feature 1 folder (branch) and use it for feature 4 work, or as the picture below portrays, should I delete the feature 1 folder and simply create another folder to branch with for feature 4?  Or is it no real difference?  Perhaps there are practical issues not immediately apparent?

[image]

Picture taken from `Professional Team Foundation Server 2013`, `St. Jean et al`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Feature Branching methodology I prefer to delete the "closed" branch, and take a new one.

I do this for three reasons:

- I can name the branch to something that is relevant to the feature being worked on
- Removes any potential merge conflicts (and therefore reduces risk of regressions)
- It's entirely possible that multiple features will be worked on simultaneously and this should be done in separate branches to allow isolation.

Comment: This is a common practice, one that I also recommend. It prevents confusion weeks and months down the road.